# What'st going to prevent me from using Session over JWT for my API authentication (for express and reactjs app)

Tags: reactjs, jwt, express-session

I just want to know if JWT can't be stored in localstorage or cookies cause its gonna be hacked that way then way the heck they created it, whats the problem that JWT solves that session cant.

i really want to know :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a software developer, I choose among them due to the requirements of the specific project I am working on.

As far as my knowledge goes, JWT can be a better alternative to sessions whenever the project is **tight on storage** (database) and can be a **little faster** as there will not be any database request to see the token's payload.

It has also its own disadvantages such as the reduced security compared to sessions where stolen, anyone can CRUD anything in your app with a false identity for which there is **no revocation** technique of the token back unless it expires in the time set.

Sessions also have their own advantages and disadvantages especially helpful on server side rendered apps *for my case* but I think you should take into account both alternatives according to the requirements of the project in which the technique is to be used in.

Comment: A point of addition is that as you are using your JWT with a react app you can simply store the token as a state and not in the localStorage or cookies. and while transferring them to your backend you could send as a bearer token header.

Comment: But i can store sessions in redis or any other caching DB if i want to go fast, and also sessions is also not specific to server side rendered apps as i know, you can use it to authenticate your api, there is no problem, **but i want to know whats the problem that jwt solve that sessions cant :) Thanks anyway**

Comment: I totally get that you can stroe sessions in Redis or other caching DBs but that is the problem that I think JWT solves the most. Imagine having to a website with many many users eg 2000 that all authenticate at the same time. Time taken to check for the cookie in the database is increased which reduces the speed of your server. Also as the users are 2000 in number, It would require extra resources to store those user's cookies all at once. **Cookies & JWT do the same work but JWT saves storage and time on the server side**. I hope this is more clear.

Comment: Another thing JWT is capable that cookies aren't is to store a payload of data. JWT can store informations about the owner of the token whereas cookies can't.

Comment: I very glad I answered you and for some futher comparison between cookies and JWT you can checkout: [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/cookies-vs-tokens-the-definitive-guide) or [this one too is helpful](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens). And feel free to accept the answer and up vote. Thanks a lot too **@wassim Ben Jdida**